# How to remove Conjugate when it appears in a real-valued expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, expression-manipulation

I evaluated

```
Refine[
  Conjugate[
    (-4 I kp^3 v^3 - 4 γ21 γ31 γ41 + 4 kp^2 v^2 (γ21 + γ31 + γ41 - 3 I δp))
      // Expand],
  (γ21 | γ31 | γ41 | kp | δp | v) ∈ Reals] // FullSimplify
```

and got

```
(* 4 (-γ21 γ31 γ41 + kp^2 v^2 (γ21 + γ31 + γ41) + 
   I Conjugate[kp]^2 Conjugate[v]^2 (Conjugate[kp v] + 3 Conjugate[δp])) *)
```

How can I remove `Conjugate` from my result?

Comment: `FullSimplify[
 Refine[Conjugate[(-4 I kp^3 v^3 - 
      4 \[Gamma]21 \[Gamma]31 \[Gamma]41 + 
      4 kp^2 v^2 (\[Gamma]21 + \[Gamma]31 + \[Gamma]41 - 
         3 I \[Delta]p)) // 
    Expand]], (\[Gamma]21 | \[Gamma]31 | \[Gamma]41 | kp | \[Delta]p |
     v) \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: Since I had to copy @ciao's code above and paste it into a notebook to notice the difference, I'll just write it out explicitly: ciao is suggesting that the right placement for those domain assumptions is as an option to `FullSimplify`, and not within `Refine` (which works perfectly). This Q&A exchange must have won some prize for terseness ;-)

Comment: There is always `/. Conjugate -> Identity`.  Use at your own risk.

Comment: Actually, this is what `ComplexExpand` is for: `Conjugate[(-4 I kp^3 v^3-4 \[Gamma]21 \[Gamma]31 \[Gamma]41+4 kp^2 v^2 (\[Gamma]21+\[Gamma]31+\[Gamma]41-3 I \[Delta]p))//Expand]//ComplexExpand//FullSimplify`

Comment: `FullSimplify[Conjugate[-4 I kp^3 v^3 - 4 γ21 γ31 γ41 + 4 kp^2 v^2 (γ21 + γ31 + γ41 - 3 I δp)], (γ21 | γ31 | γ41 | kp | δp | v) ∈ Reals]` also works well in this case, and does not require `Refine` or `Expand`.